Import image in scss / Astro
Using Astro and Sass I would like to use an asset image in a scss file.
In the scss file I have:
.map {
    background-image: url('src/assets/map.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

In the index.astro I import it as
---
import 'src/styles/global.scss';

---

When I use the astro dev I shows the image just fine but when I build it the image isn't compiled into the final dist.
Is there a way to import the image into the scss?
Is this possible at all to import the image or do I just have to put it in the public folder and point to that path in the scss?

1.Place the images in the public folder, then directly reference their paths in the SCSS file.
2.If webpack is used, use URL Loader to handle image files.

Guess I'll just go with option 1 :)
